# Emulator (AVD) won't start

Tags: android, eclipse, dns, emulation, launch

Whenever I tried to run any projects from my eclipse following message thrown up in the console window

```
[2014-07-30 06:32:53 - Project_Name] ------------------------------
[2014-07-30 06:32:53 - Project_Name] Android Launch!
[2014-07-30 06:32:53 - Project_Name] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-30 06:32:53 - Project_Name] Performing com.example.workingver1.HomeScreen activity launch
[2014-07-30 06:32:54 - Project_Name] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD_for_5_4_FWVGA'
[2014-07-30 06:32:54 - Project_Name] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_for_5_4_FWVGA'
[2014-07-30 06:32:54 - Emulator] unknown option: -dns
[2014-07-30 06:32:54 - Emulator] please use -help for a list of valid options
```

What could be the problem?

I tried following things but couldn't rectify it.

1. Clean Project and Run
2. Tried Windows->preference->launch (Launch Settings)
3. Delete my existing AVD and Create a new one, that too didn't work

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Eclipse
Select Windows -> Preference

Android -> Launch -> Default Emulator Option ->

Paste this:  -Dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
than Apply -> OK

clean up your project

check for ANDROID ARM system image is available installed properly

open Android virtual device
check your API levels properly 
select Arm
it might be an ARM Ram problem too .. if you use core i3 system processor  choose 512 ram in Avd or choose any other emulator with 512 Ram I suggest you to go with android API level 19 or 20 with Android Nexus one Emulator its the better emulator which starts easily.
and
start the emulator launch it

once your Emulator starts running then run your app

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

clean up the project

set the default emulator option in windows
1. preference
2. android
3. launch